# Manage ListView contextual menu while listview displayed content changes

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I have a fragment in which I display a listview with lets say 3 items : A, B and C
I long press on B to display a contextual menu. Then once this menu is displayed a background process updates the data and removes A from the adapter (cursor adapter + notifydatasetchanged). My contextual menu is still displayed. Now I press on a contextual menu entry and the selected action is applied to the item C (now position 2nd position in my list) where it should be applies to item B (2nd position when I opened the contextual menu but now 1st position).
This works fine in Android 2.x, but fails with Android 4.1-4.4

Any idea why ?

Please find below my code

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            final MenuInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);

            // don't forget to set the title !
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) info.targetView.getTag();

...
}

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) info.targetView.getTag();
        int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();

        switch (menuItemIndex) {
        case R.id.entry1 :
            process(viewHolder);
            break;
        }

...
}
```

Comment: use `public long id` of AdapterContextMenuInfo, it will probably be the same

Comment: what do you mean exactly ? I need to retrieve the same viewHolder than the one extracted in onCreateContextMenu

Comment: viewHolder? why do you need it? they are only for improving the performance of your ListView (and this is very, very doubtful, see http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/11/is-findviewbyid-slow.html)

Comment: Until the recyclingViews they were necessary for performance. But there I use it to store my item. I don't understand what your suggestion is to help me solve my issue

Comment: if you have an id you can lookup your data in your adapter, view holder is not meant to act as your data model

Comment: This isn't what I need. I need to retrieve the data used to create the contextMenu. Looking up my data will work exactly like it is already working => it will retrieve a different item than the one retrieved at the time of the contextmenu creation

Comment: no, using an id you will get the proper data, since the id doesn't change in your model, in your current implementation view holder changes after deletion one of the item from your model and thats why cannot be used as a data model replacement

Comment: then can you please show some code sample because I don't see how you can achive this. Thanks

Comment: what adapter are you using? a custom one?

Comment: so get the data directly from the model: in your case do a query: select * from my_table where _id = ?